# Forceclose issue on soundboard with some androids?

Tags: android, button, sdk, crash

Ok, my problem is that when I open up the app I made it forces closes when I try to click some of the songs. It is weird bc it works good on Galaxy Tab but not for Galaxy S, droid 2, vibrant, etc. Here is the code I use for the thing:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MyMain extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    MediaPlayer mpButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer pButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer oButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer tButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer sButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer aButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer dButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer cButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer lButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer himButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer herButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer hellButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer mocButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer rasButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer raseButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer dalekButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer sharButtonClick;
    MediaPlayer godButtonClick;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      //set up the button sounds
  mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.money);

        Button bmoney = (Button) findViewById(R.id.money);
        bmoney.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mpButtonClick.start();

            }
        });


      pButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pants);

        Button bpants = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pants);
        bpants.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pButtonClick.start();

            }       


        });

   oButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.oath);

        Button oath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oath);
        oath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                oButtonClick.start();

            }       


        });

     tButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tardis);

        Button tardis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tardis);
        tardis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tButtonClick.start();

            }       


        });

     sButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.screwdriver);

        Button screwdriver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.screwdriver);
        screwdriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sButtonClick.start();

            }       


        });

      aButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);

        Button alarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm);
        alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                aButtonClick.start();

            }       


        });

     dButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kame);

        Button kame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kame);
        kame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

     cButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.card);

        Button card = (Button) findViewById(R.id.card);
        card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

    lButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.laugh);

        Button laugh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.laugh);
        laugh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                lButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

himButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.him);

        Button him = (Button) findViewById(R.id.him);
        him.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                himButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

herButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.her);

        Button her = (Button) findViewById(R.id.her);
        her.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                herButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

hellButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hell);

        Button hell = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hell);
        hell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                hellButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

mocButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mocking);

        Button mocking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mocking);
        mocking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mocButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

godButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.god);

        Button god = (Button) findViewById(R.id.god);
        god.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                godButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

rasButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rasengan);

        Button rasengan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rasengan);
        rasengan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rasButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

raseButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rasen);

        Button rasen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rasen);
        rasen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                raseButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

dalekButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dalek);

        Button dalek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dalek);
        dalek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dalekButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });

sharButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sharingan);

        Button sharingan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sharingan);
        sharingan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sharButtonClick.start();

            }       

            });




    }


}
```

Sorry for the long code I just really need help

Edit: If it helps I always get:

java.lang.NullPointerException
MyMain$8.onClick()

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the fc error.  Use logcat: open the DDMS perspective in eclipse, or run `adb logcat` from the command line.

Comment: That is not the full stacktrace, that is just the first line of it.  Please post the full stacktrace, and tell us which line in your code it is pointing to.  Something on that line is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without haveing a logcat output or stack trace to work from, my guess is that you are making most devices scream for mercy by loading that many `MediaPlayer` instances into memory at one time!  Calling `MediaPlayer.create()` not only creates another instance, it also calls `prepare()` on it and get it ready to roll.  Perhaps try a more streamlined approach:

```
public class MyMain extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Set up the buttons
    Button bmoney = (Button) findViewById(R.id.money);
    bmoney.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.money);
        }
    });

    Button bpants = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pants);
    bpants.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.pants);
        }       
    });

    Button oath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oath);
    oath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.oath);
        }       
    });

    Button tardis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tardis);
    tardis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.tardis);
        }       
    });

    Button screwdriver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.screwdriver);
    screwdriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.screwdriver);
        }       
    });

    Button alarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm);
    alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.alarm);
        }       
    });

    Button kame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kame);
    kame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.kame);
        }       
    });

    Button card = (Button) findViewById(R.id.card);
    card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.card);
        }       

    });

    Button laugh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.laugh);
    laugh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.laugh);
        }       
    });

    Button him = (Button) findViewById(R.id.him);
    him.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.him);
        }       
    });

    Button her = (Button) findViewById(R.id.her);
    her.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.her);
        }       
    });

    Button hell = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hell);
    hell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.hell);
        }       
    });

    Button mocking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mocking);
    mocking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.mocking);
        }       
    });

    Button god = (Button) findViewById(R.id.god);
    god.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.god);
        }       
    });

    Button rasengan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rasengan);
    rasengan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.rasengan);
        }       
    });

    Button rasen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rasen);
    rasen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.rasen);
        }       
    });

    Button dalek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dalek);
    dalek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.dalek);
        }       
    });

    Button sharingan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sharingan);
    sharingan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.sharingan);
        }       
    });
}

//Consolidate media playing to one location
private void playSound(int resId) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mp.start();
}

//Completion listener method
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.release();
}

}
```

This method will create the `MediaPlayer` instance and play the sound only at the time you need it.  Once complete, the listener can release the resources to keep your memory footprint reasonable.

You could also streamline this code further by making use of android:onClick in your XML to have all the buttons call one method, and then call `playSound()` with the right id based on the button id (unless your targeting 1.5, of course).

Hope that helps!

Comment: That was the problem ty. I didn't realize that calling MediaPlayer so many times could do all that ty again :)